# Read a struct from file

Tags: c, linux, file, io, posix

I am trying to write a struct of 4 unsigned integers in a file and then read it back, but I can not read anything.

Here is my code:

```
// create and write values in superblock
..
Superblock s; // the struct
if(write(file_desc , &superblock , sizeof(Superblock)) == -1) {
  perror("writing superblock");
  exit(1);
}
close(file_desc);
file_desc = open(path_file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0600);
while ( ( read( file_desc , &s , sizeof(Superblock))) > 0 ) {
  printf("%u %u %u %u\n", s.block_size, s.filename_size, s.max_file_size,
         s.max_dir_file_no);
}
```

It will not even enter the loop. What am I missing?

Comment: It's a bad idea to directly read/write structures to disk. They can contain padding, which is highly compiler-dependent.

Comment: Yes, it's better to direclty serialize each field of the structure, that gives you control over which bits are part of the external representation. With a direct write of the entire struct, you have no such control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are opening the file for write only (`O_WRONLY`) and then trying to `read` from it.

Comment: That's it! By the way do you know how will `write()` behave when its third argument is greater than the size of the struct?

Comment: @G.Samaras I am fairly sure that would in most cases invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @G.Samaras as the second argument is just an address, write will read 3rd arg. many bytes starting with this address. Remember Heardbleed bug?